# Как отформатировать данные из localstorage?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, localstorage

Имею в `localstorage` данные в таком виде:

```
{"SCI-3":{"quantity":5,"id":"SCI-3","price":4000,"name":"Проба","thumb":"photo.png","size":"80×80","link":"proba.html"},"SCI-4":{"quantity":1,"id":"SCI-4","name":"Проба","thumb":"photo.png","size":"20×20","link":"proba.html"}}
```

SCI может быть много с разными номерами.
Я вытянул из `localstorage` выше написанные данные для того чтобы использовать как значение в `textarea`.

Вопрос:
Можно данные перед вставкой в `textarea` привести к такому виду? Ну и как это сделать?

```
<textarea>

№: SCI-3
Название: Проба
Ссылка: proba.html
Фото: photo.png
Размер: 80×80
Количество: 5
Сумма: 4000

№: SCI-4
Название: Проба
Ссылка: proba.html
Фото: photo.png
Размер: 20×20
Количество: 1
Сумма: 

</textarea>
```

Comment: Привести можно. Делаете цикл по объекту, строите строку. Строку записываете в textarea.

Comment: Можно, а в чем сложность? Напишите для объекта функцию перевода в строку под нужный формат

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Собственно пробегаемся и выводим, то, что нужно.

```js
var data = {"SCI-3":{"quantity":5,"id":"SCI-3","price":4000,"name":"Проба","thumb":"photo.png","size":"80×80","link":"proba.html"},"SCI-4":{"quantity":1,"id":"SCI-4","name":"Проба","thumb":"photo.png","size":"20×20","link":"proba.html"}};

var text = '';

for(element in data){

  text += "№ "+element+"\r\n";
  text += "Название: "+data[element]['name']+"\r\n";
  text += "Ссылка: "+data[element]['link']+"\r\n";
  text += "Фото: "+data[element]['thumb']+"\r\n";
  text += "Размер: "+data[element]['size']+"\r\n";
  text += "Количество: "+data[element]['quantity']+"\r\n";
  text += "Сумма:\r\n\r\n";
}

document.querySelector('textarea').value = text;
```

```css
textarea {
  height: 250px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```